# RecyclerView creates more views that have not display when invokes recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use `RecyclerView` in Android to show a list

here is Adapter's code:

```
class MAdapter(private val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<MViewHolder>() {

    var list = ArrayList<ListItem>()

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.e("test", "POSITION "+position)
        val listItem = list[position]
        holder.title.text = listItem.title
        holder.content.text = listItem.content
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MViewHolder {
        val llView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_item_listview, parent, false)
        //
        return MViewHolder(llView)
    }
}
```

And in `Activity.OnCreate()`:

```
val adapter = MAdapter(this)
    val list = ArrayList<ListItem>()
    (0..31).mapTo(list) { ListItem("title$it", "content$it") }
    adapter.list = list
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
```

In my screen, it should show 10 items. If I don't invoke `smoothScrollToPositon()`, it will just create 10 items in `RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder()`. But if invokes `smoothScrollToPositon()`, the LOGCAT printed in `onBindViewHolder()` would print 20 items, from 0 to 19, but the screen always show 10 items(from 0 to 9).

I confuse that why it happens? Does method `smoothScrollToPosition()` do something specially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to @GParekar， your answer show me a lot.
I go through my sample codes in RecyclerView step by step, then find a key method in RecyclerView.LayoutManager 'getExtraLayoutSpace()'

```
protected int getExtraLayoutSpace(RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (state.hasTargetScrollPosition()) {
        return mOrientationHelper.getTotalSpace();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

as per document, this method returns the amount of extra space that should be laid out by LayoutManager. By default, LinearLayoutManager lays out 1 extra page of items while smooth scrolling and 0 otherwise.

So, if method smoothScrollToPosition() is not be called, the method 'getExtraLayoutSpace()' will return 0 by default. Otherwise, it would return current layout's total space then we would get a double-space(2x) for RecyclerView's items. That why 'onBindViewHolder' will be called 2x times items after calling smoothScrollToPosition().

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation:

`RecyclerView.LayoutManager` to be able to detect data set changes in batches during a layout calculation.

`RecyclerView.LayoutManager` is responsible for creating the actual scroll action.

`recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(0);` - Starts a smooth scroll to an adapter position.

Whenever `recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(0);` is called, it goes through all data set and smooth scroll to given particular position.

`RecyclerView.LayoutManager` inflate only 10 items because data set not changed during `smoothScrollToPosition()` method calling.

Suppose user at particular position and `smoothScrollToPosition()` method called for position 0. it goes all data set that time  `onBindViewHolder()` method called from user last position(i.e. from where user scrolled the list).

For example suppose on screen inflate 4 items  then user scroll up to 10 item.

Whenever `smoothScrollToPosition()` called then `onBindViewHolder()` will call 4 times i.e position 3 to 0 because user scrolled list from position 4.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't understand that why it calls onBindViewHoldere() for so many times after calling smoothScrollToPosition(); The list has 32 items, and RecyclerView just show only 10 items on screen. So I think it should call 10 times on onBindViewHolder(). But after calling smoothScrollToPosition(0), there are 20 times(2x) called on onBindViewHolder(). You said that RecyclerView would go through all data set, but why not the onBindViewHolder() be called 32 times cause there are 32 items in list?